# declare and initialize an array of pointers to function in 2 lines in c

Tags: c, arrays

I'm recoding printf and I have to respect a norm to not have more that 80 characters per line but my array of pointers to function is more than that so I'm wondering if there is way to split the inialization and the declaration of my array of pointers to function

here is my array

```
void (*tfnc[8]) (va_list *, s_struct *) = {conv_c, conv_s, conv_p, conv_id, conv_id, conv_u, conv_x, conv_X};
```

Comment: In C, you can press enter almost anywhere you want, except in the middle of words or strings.

Comment: I didn't know that it was a possibility thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with breaking down the statement to use more than one line?

```
void (*tfnc[8]) (va_list *, s_struct *) 
      = {conv_c, conv_s, conv_p, conv_id, conv_id, conv_u, conv_x, conv_X};
```

Comment: I didn't know that I could write it like that I feel dumb now but thank you very much anyway

Answer (score 1):

yes,

```
void (*tfnc[8]) (va_list *, s_struct *) =
           {conv_c, conv_s, conv_p, conv_id, conv_id, conv_u, conv_x, conv_X};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference - a more conventional coding style would be something like this:

```
typedef void tfnc_t (va_list*, s_struct*);

...

tfnc_t* tfnc [8] = 
{
  conv_c, 
  conv_s, 
  conv_p, 
  conv_id, 
  conv_id, 
  conv_u, 
  conv_x, 
  conv_X
};
```

Is it 2 lines? No.
Is it more readable that some one-line goo? Yes, by far.